# output for find-s algorithm

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning

I am trying to print the maximally specific hypothesis as an output for the find-S algorithm.

I am getting the wrong output

I have written a basic code in python to do so.

```
import csv
with open('C:/Users/User_name/tennis.csv','r')as f:
 reader=csv.reader(f)   
 your_list=list(reader)

 h=[['0','0','0','0','0','0']]
 for i in your_list:
     print(i)
     if i[-1] =="True":
         j=0
         for x in i:
             if x !="True":
                 if x !=h[0][j] and h[0][j]=='0':
                     h[0][j]=x
                 elif x!=h[0][j] and h[0][j]!='0':
                     h[0][j]='?'
                 else:
                     pass
         j=j+1
 print("the maximally specific hypothesis is",h) 

['sky', 'temp', 'humidity', 'wind', 'water', 'forecast', 'target']
['sunny', 'warm', 'normal', 'strong', 'warm', 'same', 'True']
['sunny', 'warm', 'high', 'strong', 'warm', 'same', 'True']
['rainy', 'cold', 'high', 'strong', 'warm', 'change', 'False']
['sunny', 'warm', 'high', 'strong', 'cool', 'change', 'True']
```

The maximally specific hypothesis is

```
[['?', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

This is the output,I am getting but this is the output I am supposed to get:

```
[['sunny','warm','?','strong','?','?']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct Please move the `j=j+1` inside the `for` loop.

```
import csv
with open('C:/Users/User_name/tennis.csv','r')as f:
 reader=csv.reader(f)   
 your_list=list(reader)

 h=[['0','0','0','0','0','0']]
 for i in your_list:
     print(i)
     if i[-1] =="True":
         j=0
         for x in i:
             if x !="True":
                 if x !=h[0][j] and h[0][j]=='0':
                     h[0][j]=x
                 elif x!=h[0][j] and h[0][j]!='0':
                     h[0][j]='?'
             j=j+1
 print("the maximally specific hypothesis is",h) 

['sky', 'temp', 'humidity', 'wind', 'water', 'forecast', 'target']
['sunny', 'warm', 'normal', 'strong', 'warm', 'same', 'True']
['sunny', 'warm', 'high', 'strong', 'warm', 'same', 'True']
['rainy', 'cold', 'high', 'strong', 'warm', 'change', 'False']
['sunny', 'warm', 'high', 'strong', 'cool', 'change', 'True']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#to read the data in the csv file
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(data,"n")

#making an array of all the attributes
d = np.array(data)[:,:-1]
print("n The attributes are: ",d)

#segragating the target that has positive and negative examples
target = np.array(data)[:,-1]
print("n The target is: ",target)

#training function to implement find-s algorithm
def train(c,t):
    for i, val in enumerate(t):
        if val == "Yes":
            specific_hypothesis = c[i].copy()
            break
         
    for i, val in enumerate(c):
        if t[i] == "Yes":
            for x in range(len(specific_hypothesis)):
                if val[x] != specific_hypothesis[x]:
                    specific_hypothesis[x] = '?'
                else:
                    pass
             
    return specific_hypothesis

#obtaining the final hypothesis
print("n The final hypothesis is:",train(d,target))



My data set is:
   Sunny  Warm Normal  Strong Warm.1    Same  Yes
0  Sunny  Warm   High  Strong   Warm    Same  Yes
1  Rainy  Cold   High  Strong   Warm  Change   No
2  Sunny  Warm   High  Strong   Cool  Change  Yes

Final Correct output is:
The final hypothesis is: ['Sunny' 'Warm' 'High' 'Strong' '?' '?']
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.